# Artifactory login problem after upgrade from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: artifactory

I upgraded my Artifactory Pro server from version 6.x to 7.x.
I have ldap authentication with MS ActiveDirectory After upgrade some users cannot login to the web-gui with 500 error. I founded error in artifactory logs:

```
2020-07-17T07:50:44.288Z [jffe ] [ERROR] [6261074d6e4d564 ] [                              ] [main                ] - http request failed with code - BAD_REQUEST
2020-07-17T07:50:44.288Z [jffe ] [ERROR] [6261074d6e4d564 ] [                              ] [main                ] - http request failed with message - Could not find user 'ad-test-usr'
2020-07-17T07:50:44.289Z [jffe ] [ERROR] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/@jfrog/access-nodejs-client/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/@jfrog/access-nodejs-client/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/@jfrog/access-nodejs-client/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

But user exist in AD and in Artifactory.

Comment: Any solution @DmitryT

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, in version 6.x logins are case insensitive “UserID” and “userid” are valid both and I can login with any of them.
In version 7.x login is case sensitive and valid is only with lower case “userid”